# String distance which includes overflowing numbers / carries

Tags: string-comparison, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-comparison

Is there a string distance measurement method where the distance between `Abc099mnop` and `Abc100mnop` is not 3 but just 1 because it detects that 099 + 1 = 100, i.e. the **carry**? Maybe even one which works with hexadecimals (`AB01ff` -> `AB0200`) or alphabetic (`abcDzz` -> `abcEaa`) distances?

I don't expect this to be more than a standard method which tries to replace each substitution sequence with this addition (or possibly subtraction), but I *do* expect this to have a name and implementation already.

The ability to also find insertions/deletions when no previous padding is present (`A9` -> `A10`) also comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any existing implementation or algorithm, but I'm intrigued so I've created two issues in liblevenshtein for the purpose:

1. https://github.com/universal-automata/liblevenshtein-java/issues/58
2. https://github.com/universal-automata/liblevenshtein-java/issues/59